# Ubuntu 20.04/22.04 on HDD with dual boot can not completely shutdown

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, shutdown

I have a desktop with MSI-Z690 motherboard and installed Dual boot Windows 11 on SSD and Ubuntu 20.04 on HDD (recently upgraded to 22.04 dev-branch the issue still exists).

I choose Ubuntu at the first priority boot and Windows 11 is in Ubuntu bootloader, and it works fine.

The Windows works well. But when I power-off Ubuntu, all software quit but display still on, nothing on display but the signal is still there, and some light on black screen. The fan is still running, and I have to hold the power button for about 5 seconds to shut it down.

I set grub to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""` and the last line of log is `reached target system power off` and it will stuck seems forever(I have once waited for 120 mins)

How to set my Ubuntu to the really normal behavior?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *jammy* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 14 April 2022, and isn't on-topic here until release on 21 April 2022.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *jammy* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: If you wish to report bugs, firstly thank you for helping test the release, but please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs and use a #ubuntu+1 site such as IRC, https://ubuntuforums.org/ etc. *This site isn't tracked for ubuntu+1 or #ubuntu-next issues*   Also don't forget it's still in *alpha* with *beta* freeze scheduled for 28-March-2022 & *beta* release 31-March-2022

Comment: @guiverc thanks, I would report as you suggest.